# Python Pickle acting differently when iterating through large number of files vs small number

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, pickle

I am trying to iterate through dictionaries using pickle, and it seems work fine for individual files, and when I iterate through small batches of files, but when I do more, something wonky happens. Here is the code I have:

```
   def search_dictionary():
    with open('full_set_name.txt', 'r') as file:
        set_name = []
        for f in file:
           set_name.append(f.strip('\n'))
        count = 0
        while count < 24:
            pickle_in = open("{0}.pickle".format(set_name[count]), 'rb')
            card_d = pickle.load(pickle_in)
            print (set_name[count], card_d)
            count +=1
```

When I run this code with `while count` being less than 24 , Each dictionary prints out as expected wit each dictionary being printed in order of the list. when I do 24 or more, contents from `set_name` are at the top of the console, not in a dictionary. Each name from the list appearing hundreds of times.
 I ran each of these files independently and each dictionary printed out just fine. If run `while count < len(set_name)` which will be all dictionaries, I get the error:

```
card_d = pickle.load(pickle_in)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

From what I've read, it happens when you try to read an empty pickle file. The contents of each pickle definitely has a dictionary. Is there something wrong with my syntax? Or maybe a file got corrupted? How would I tell? The contents look fine if I print them individually. I did use dictionary comprehension to change the keys of each dictionary to lowercase. Is it possible it was corrupted that way? Here is the code I ran:

```
count = 0
with open('full_set_name.txt') as sets:
    set_list = []
    for s in sets:
        set_list.append(s.rstrip())
    while count < len(set_list):
        pickle_in = open('{0}.pickle'.format(set_list[198]), 'rb')
        file = pickle.load(pickle_in)
        file =  {k.lower(): v for k, v in file.items()}

        pickle.dump(file, open('{0}.pickle'.format(set_list[198]), 'wb'))
        print (file)
        count += 1
```

What do you guys think? I'm sure I probably did somethin dumb, but I cannot figure out the actual problem. I have a picture to show what the first line looks like. It should be a dictionary, and it's actually the contents of the `set_name` list multiplied hundreds of times. Couldn't paste it. Thanks for taking a look[image]

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because it lacks an MCVE.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  How would I recreate the problem with a stand in files? I could normally create a few stand-in dictionaries, but that problem seems to be related to there being a large amount of files. Even your help with that would be awesome.

Comment: You can generate files. Maybe it's not the number, but the content of a specific file greater 24? Maybe the collective size? In any case it's your task to reduce the problem before posting. The simple reason is that it forces you to focus on just the problem, which avoids many stupid questions that are just small glitches. Also, it makes sure that others can reproduce the issue!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That's a good point, thanks. I'll work on recreating the problem in a more simple format. If I still can't figure out the problem, I'll repost and makes sure it meets the standards of MCVE.